# Jquery change border color of div when mouse over another div

Tags: jquery

Hey guys I'm not sure why this isn't working... seems like it should, thanks for the help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.newProductLearnMore').hover(function() {
    $('.newProductDesc').css('borderTop', '5px solid #006699');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="newProductWrapper" style="margin-top: -100px;">
  <div class="newProductImage">
    <img src="" alt="" height="300" width="550">
  </div>
  <div class="newProductDesc"> <span class="name">test</span>
    <br /> <span class="desc">test</span>

  </div>
  <a href=#>
    <div class="newProductLearnMore"><span>LEARN MORE!</span>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: How exactly it isn't working?

Comment: You're missing a `)`

Comment: I was missing it, I've modified the code and it still doesn't work?

Comment: It seems to work in the snippet

Comment: Do you want it to do something on mouseleave, like remove that styling?

Comment: I had something else going on it works now. And yes I will want a mouse out. and I have a few of the same div  groups but only want the one I hover over to change, not sure how to do that either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the mouseenter and mouseleave event handler

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.newProductLearnMore').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.newProductDesc').css('borderTop', '5px solid #006699');
    });

    $('.newProductLearnMore').mouseleave(function() {
        //return to initial border color
    });
});
```

Comment: that's great thanks! now if I had a few of those div groups all with the same code how would I get it so just the one I'm hovering over to change. I'm trying to use the $(this) but I'm not having much luck. Thanks again!

Comment: If you are trying to use $(this). You should use delegate. But to make faster if you are new to jquery; Let each div group have it own id, then use the id to reference it instead of class. Though it will make the code longer :)